# Filter a table cell or row starting in X row

Tags: jquery, html-table

I need to select a cell from a table starting in X row.

I have this:

```
var filas = $("#table tr");
filas.each(function(index){
               console.log( $(this).children(':nth-child(2)').html() );
           });
```

And it prints in my console every row but the one I'm filtering, including the header...

### For example:

```
Table Header
1
2
4
5
6
```

### And I only want to get

```
1
2
4
5
6
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: have a look at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/CgqQt/

Answer (score 2):

You can use has selector

```
var filas = $("#table tr:has(td)");
filas.each(function(index){
               console.log( $(this).children(':nth-child(2)').html() );
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Best structure is to put the data rows in a `<tbody>` and heading row(s) in `<thead>`

```
<table id="table>
   <thead>
      <tr><th>heading</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="table-body">
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the rows you want are `$('#table-body tr')` or `$('#table tbody tr')`